# AdditionalAnswers in mockito not returning the good type

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, stub

I'm trying to stub a method using Mockito but for it to work, I need to use the parameters passed to this function.

Here is my code right now, but it doesn't compile:

```
when(layer.createNewPlaylist("playlist1", Mockito.any(UUID.class))).thenReturn(new OnDemandPlaylist("playlist1", "", AdditionalAnswers.returnsArgAt(1)));
```

To summarize, I want the second parameter to be passed to the new object that is returned.

Right now, I have this error:

```
The constructor OnDemandPlaylist(String, String, Answer<Object>) is undefined
```

***EDIT***

I have found a solution using "old" ways of querying the arguments and share it here. But I would like to know if there is a simpler way using the thenReturn syntax and the AdditionalAnswers.

```
when(layer.createNewPlaylist(Mockito.eq("playlist1"), Mockito.any(UUID.class)))
            .thenAnswer(new Answer<OnDemandPlaylist>() {
                 public OnDemandPlaylist answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                     Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                     return new OnDemandPlaylist("playlist1", "", (UUID)args[1]);
                     }
                 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is misusing the Mockito API :

```
when(layer.createNewPlaylist("playlist1", Mockito.any(UUID.class)))
    .thenReturn(new OnDemandPlaylist("playlist1", "", AdditionalAnswers.returnsArgAt(1)));
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                this is wrong
```

`AdditionalAnswers.returnsArgAt(1)` returns an `Answer` that will return arg at position 1 (whose type is not known at compilation), so this is kinda expected that there's a compilation error on the constructor as the third argument is a `UUID`, not a Mockito `Answer`.

`AdditionalAnswers.returnsArgAt(1)` usage is documented in the javadoc :

```
This additional answer could be used at stub time using the then|do|willAnswer methods. For example :

given(person.remember(dream1, dream2, dream3, dream4)).will(returnsArgAt(3));
doAnswer(returnsArgAt(3)).when(person).remember(dream1, dream2, dream3, dream4);
```

---

Your solution is actually the correct way to do what you want. Even having all the argument matchers to stub the invocation. Note that making the stub more readable has a great advantage for future refactoring:

```
when(layer.createNewPlaylist(eq("playlist1"), any(UUID.class))).then(playlistWithSameUUID);

public Answer<OnDemandPlaylist> playlistWithSameUUID() {
    return new Answer<OnDemandPlaylist>() {
                 public OnDemandPlaylist answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                     Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                     return new OnDemandPlaylist("playlist1", "", (UUID)args[1]);
                     }
                 };
}
```